# Converting string with format "2014-08-12-12:42:38:133936" to datetime

Tags: t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I have an issue converting this string coming from a web service into a datetime for our database.

I know I could take a substring of each side date / time and format the hell out of it so that i would essentially break it apart and add the time back to the date, but there has to be a more simple way. I am terrified if I do it the "hack" way then somewhere down the line there will be a date that will break the logic.

So does anyone have a tip in converting a string with the format "2014-08-12-12:42:38:133936" into a Datetime datatype?

Comment: Use **CAST** and **CONVERT** tsql function.

Comment: do you need to keep the accuracy to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmmmm or you are happy with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to need to keep the accuracy to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmmmmm or you are happy with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(MAX) = '2014-08-12-12:42:38:133936'

SELECT  convert(datetime,  STUFF(SUBSTRING(@value,1,LEN(@value)-3),11,1,' '), 21)
```

or

```
SELECT  CAST(STUFF(SUBSTRING(@value,1,LEN(@value)-3),11,1,' ')AS DATETIME )
```